# Снипеты VS Code . Регулярные выражения

Tags: visual-studio-code

Хотелось бы вводить через доллар переменную и чтобы она потом выводилась с большой буквы .

В доках по VS Code есть пример

"${TM_FILENAME/(.*)/${1:/upcase}/}"  что выводит EXAMPLE-123.456-TEST.JS .

Это работает (ТМ_FILENAME - встроенный снипет для имени файла )

Я же пробую вставить вместо TM_FILENAME свою переменную и тогда уже ничего не работает . Что же не так в этом случае ?

Answer (score 0):

Заработало. нужно писать цифрой переменную - 1 например  (это вместо ТМ_..) . А потом еще Tab нажать не забыть . А и регулярное выражение я поставил [a-z] .